# Search text in html using Xpath and continue the search from next element for further search in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

```
<html>
    <body>

        <p>This is 
            <sub>subscripted</sub> 
            text1.
        </p>
        <p>This is 
            <sub>subscripted</sub> 
            text2.
        </p>
        <p>This is 
            <sub>subscripted</sub> 
            text3.
        </p>
        <p>This is 
            <sub>subscripted</sub> 
            text4.
        </p>
        <p>This is 
            <sub>subscripted</sub> 
            text5.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above shown is a dummy code snippet. My requirement is to search for `"This is subscripted text1"`. After locating this i have to search from next `<p>` element for another string match. How to use the `xpath` for this requirement . Or suggest any other idea

Comment: What is your target element? Show expected output

Comment: function getElementByXpath(path){return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;}
 elem = getElementByXpath('//*[text()[contains(.,\"'+corpus[k]+'\")]]');

Comment: I'm not sure that this might be considered as  answer on my question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847941/jquery-loop-continue-from-next-element      related to this link. i need the code in javascript and locate the string using xpath. as output i need the element which contains the text

Comment: Do you want to locate `<p>` element that contains `"This is subscripted text1"` or `<sub>` of this element or next `<p>` element?

Comment: i want to locate the first <p> for searching this is subscripted text1 and next search for this is subscripted text4 should start from succeeding <p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a sibling `p` element along the `following-sibling` axis:

```js
var p = document.evaluate('//p[normalize-space() = "This is subscripted text2."]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
if (p != null) {
  var siblingP = document.evaluate('following-sibling::p[normalize-space() = "This is subscripted text4."]', p, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
  if (siblingP != null) {
    console.log(siblingP);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="p0">This is 
            <sub>subscripted</sub> 
            text4.
        </p>
        <p id="p1">This is 
            <sub>subscripted</sub> 
            text1.
        </p>
        <p>This is 
            <sub>subscripted</sub> 
            text2.
        </p>
        <p>This is 
            <sub>subscripted</sub> 
            text3.
        </p>
        <p id="p4">This is 
            <sub>subscripted</sub> 
            text4.
        </p>
        <p>This is 
            <sub>subscripted</sub> 
            text5.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```